# Google Analytics shows sessions but zero users

Tags: google-analytics

Is this crazy?

[image]

Why is Google Analytics showing sessions but no users?

Comment: One column shows sessions over a period of time, usually 30 days, and the other two are new sessions and users. You cannot compare the two. The highlighted metrics make sense.

Comment: Technically you have zero **new** users in your screen shot.   It doesn't say anything about how many **returning** users they may be.  Do you have the same problem in reports that show all users as opposed to just new users?